# Java Regular expressions for filename

Tags: java, regex

I want to check the filenames sent to me against two patterns.

The first regular expression is ~*~, which should match names like ~263~. I put this in online regular expression testers and it matches. The code doesnt work though. Says no match

```
List<FTPFile> ret = new ArrayList<FTPFile>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("~*~");
    Matcher matcher;
    for (FTPFile file : files) 
    {
        matcher = pattern.matcher(file.getName());
        if(matcher.matches())
        {
            ret.add(file);
        }
    }
    return ret;
```

Also the second pattern I need is *@*@* which should match strings like abc@ere@sss

Please tell me the proper patterns in java for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your pattern like,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("~.*~");
```

`~*` in your regex `~*~` will repeat the first `~` zero or more times. So it won't match the number following the first `~`. Because `matches` method tries to match the whole input string, this regex causes the match to fail. So you need to add `.*` inbetween to match strings like `~66~` or `~kjk~` . To match the strings which has only numbers present inbetween `~`, you need to  use `~\d+~`

Comment: will try this and get back to you

Comment: yes, havent had the time to figure out the second regular expression. Will try and then mark correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try Regex:**

```
\~.*\~
```

**Instead:**

```
~*~
```

**Example:**

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\~.*\\~");
```

Comment: What's the difference between `\\~.*\\~` regex and `~.*~` regex?